# Downloading YouTube to mp3 and writing metadata (artist/song title) to mp3 file using youtube-dl

Tags: metadata, mp3, extract, webm, youtube-dl

I am extracting audio only from youtube videos using `youtube-dl`.  **I would like to write the metadata (i.e. Artist Name and Song Title) into the mp3 file after downloading**.  My attempt to accomplish this starts with this code:

```
@echo off
set dl=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y6Nne8RvaA
youtube-dl --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s - %(title)s" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --add-metadata %dl%
pause
```

The output from this code is:

```
[youtube] 2Y6Nne8RvaA: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 2Y6Nne8RvaA: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] 2Y6Nne8RvaA: Extracting video information
[download] Destination: Kungs vs Cookin' on 3 Burners - This Girl.webm
[download] 100% of 3.33MiB in 00:02
[fromtitle] Could not interpret title of video as "(title)s"
[ffmpeg] Adding metadata to 'Kungs vs Cookin' on 3 Burners - This Girl.webm'
[ffmpeg] Destination: Kungs vs Cookin' on 3 Burners - This Girl.mp3
Deleting original file Kungs vs Cookin' on 3 Burners - This Girl.webm (pass -k t
o keep)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, the code adds the metadata to `.webm` filename, but not to the `.mp3` file.  It is useless to write this to the `.webm` file because the this file is deleted upon completion of the process.  **I want this metadata to be written to the `.mp3` file so that when I view songs in a folder, it will look like the following:**

[image]

This format is useful to me because I can then directly input these files into iTunes and the metadata will be intact!

I'm running Windows 7, 64bit, Python 3.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That page does not even offer an MP3 file:

```
$ youtube-dl --format mp3 2Y6Nne8RvaA
ERROR: requested format not available
```

and even if you try an end-around like you have done, it does not work:

```
$ youtube-dl --audio-format mp3 2Y6Nne8RvaA
$ ffprobe 'Kungs vs Cookin’ on 3 Burners - This Girl-2Y6Nne8RvaA.mkv'
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Kungs vs Cookin’ on 3 Burners - This Girl-2Y6Nne8RvaA.mkv':
  Duration: 00:03:17.48, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 2462 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo (default)
```

Use m4a instead:

```
youtube-dl --format m4a 2Y6Nne8RvaA
```

---

You are using:

```
--extract-audio
```

when you can just download the audio by itself:

```
youtube-dl --format m4a 2Y6Nne8RvaA
```

---

You are using:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y6Nne8RvaA
```

when you can just use:

```
2Y6Nne8RvaA
```

---

You are not using:

```
--youtube-skip-dash-manifest
```

I can tell because of this extra line:

```
[youtube] 2Y6Nne8RvaA: Downloading video info webpage
```

---

Even if everything worked the way you want, you would probably still have
trouble because of the ID3 version:

[FFmpeg metadata not showing in Windows?](//superuser.com/q/453132)

Comment: Thank you for your write-up.  As you figured out, I'm new to this and I'm learning more everyday.  Your comment was very helpful to me.